# How to install Windows 7 alongside Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: windows-7

I am currently using Ubuntu 14.04 and I need to install Windows 7 as dual boot (not VM). How can I do that? Should I create a partition with G Parted for Win7? Need advice from someone who did this successfully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you have to create a separate ntfs partition for Windows and it should be a Primary one(if your disk has MBR partition table) through gparted.

Run Windows installation disk and select custom option to install Windows on created ntfs partition.

### To create a separate ntfs partition from `/dev/sda1`

[image]

- Boot Ubuntu installation disk and click on **try Ubuntu** option on startup.
- Open gparted partition editor from dash. If the program is not installed by default then run the below commands to install gparted.

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install gparted
  ```
- Make sure that all the partitions are unmounted. Now right-click on the `/dev/sda1` partition and select **Resize/Move** option to reduce it's size(*actual space needed for your Windows*).
- After the above operation, an unallocated space will be created just below to  `/dev/sda1`
- Create a new ntfs primary partition from that unallocated space.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it seems I have another problem, I can't resize my partition. [Print](http://imageshack.com/a/img836/6055/kvdd.png)

Comment: i cant resize my portion please help

Comment: @user265211 get into [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room)

Answer (score 2):

I did it, but with some little problems. 
So I did the resize thing from Live CD, worked perfect, I've installed Windows 7 and then I've rebooted. 
And here I encountered a problem, my laptop was booting directly to Windows. So again back to Try Ubuntu and type this on terminal:

```
 sudo mount /dev/sda1 /boot 
 sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install grub-pc 
 sudo grub-install /dev/sda 
 sudo umount /boot.
```

It didn't worked perfectly, but [this tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#A1st_option_%3a_get_a_CD_including_Boot-Repair) saved me. Now I have dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 7 and it works just fine!

Comment: I know you have already done it but i would like to do it myself. Did you lose your existing ubuntu and youre setups or is everything the same ? I have gnome 3 with a lot of shells and preferences and i would like to install windows without losing my existing ubuntu.
Thanks
@Ragnar