# Installing Windows 7 alongside Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7, gparted

I'm trying to create a ntfs partition to install windows 7 and I've followed [this tutorial](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454282/how-to-install-windows-7-alongside-ubuntu-14-04) so far. But when I get to the part of resizing there's the slight problem that I can only resize the small partition as you may see in the image bellow.

gparted:

[image: gparted]

how do I fix this?

Comment: You have LVM full drive install. You only use gparted for the physical partitions, but have to first use LVM tools on the logical partitions inside the physical partitions. If dual booting with Windows usually better not to use LVM as one of advantages of LVM is its full drive ease of changing the logical partitions (not the physical). But Windows cannot install inside an LVM. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm

Answer (score 2):

I can't see your picture but one thing is you can't re-size the partition you are on.  To do that I suggest creating a thumb drive with your live distro on it and boot off of that.  Then use the thumb drives gparted to repartition your internal drive.  If the computer doesn't boot your thumb drive go to bios and change boot order to run USB first.

Comment: I booted from a pen-drive and ran gparted from the try mode of ubuntu, it didn't allow me to resize :/

Comment: did you get an error message?

Comment: Also I strongly recommend installing windows FIRST then Ubuntu sometimes windows ruins grub and other problems.